# What does "this" mean when used as a prefix for method parameters?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, language-features

I'm sure the answer is something obvious, and I'm kind of embarrassed that I don't really know the answer already, but consider the following code sample I picked up while reading "Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0":

```
public static class ControllerHelpers
{
    public static void AddRuleViolations(this ModelStateDictionary modelState, IEnumerable<RuleViolation> errors)
    {
        foreach (RuleViolation issue in errors)
            modelState.AddModelError(issue.PropertyName, issue.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

I understand what this static method is doing, but what I don't understand is what purpose the word "this" is serving in the method signature.  Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is a new C# 3.0 feature called [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

It means, that you add a new method to your ModelStateDictionary objects. You can call it like a normal method:

```
yourModelStateDictionary.AddRuleViolations( errors );
```

See, that the first parameter (the 'this'-parameter) is skipped. It assigns just ModelStateDictionary as a valid target for your extension method.

The clue is, that you can do this with any class - even sealed or 3rd party classes, like .Net framework classes (for instance on object or string).

Comment: Couldn't have put it better my self

Answer (score 1):

It means the method in question is an "extension method" and can be called as if it was a method of the class itself.  See this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It is an extention method signature, It means the "AddRuleViolations" will be treated as an extention method of ModelStateDictionary.

From MSDN.

> Extension methods enable you to "add"
>   methods to **existing types** **without**
>   creating a new derived type,
>   recompiling, or otherwise modifying
>   the original type. Extension methods
>   are a special kind of static method,
>   but they are called as if they were
>   instance methods on the extended type.
>   For client code written in C# and
>   Visual Basic, there is no apparent
>   difference between calling an
>   extension method and the methods that
>   are actually defined in a type.

Answer (score 0):

Also see here: [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guid)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It adds an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to all instances of ModelStateDictionary.