# What does "this" refer to in a C# method signature and is there a VB.NET equivalent?

Tags: c#, vb.net, signature, c#-to-vb.net

I've been watching the [ASP.NET MVC Storefront](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-1/aspnet-mvc-storefront/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-8-testing-controllers-iteration-1-complete) video series *again* and saw something that I've never noticed or payed any attention to before. I noticed there were a lot of references to `this` in the signature lists of various methods.  Here is an example of one:

```c#
public static Category WithCategoryName(this IList<Category> list, string categoryName)   
{
    return 
    (
        from s in list
        where s.Name.Equals(categoryName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        select s
    )
    .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

I immediately understand the `IList<Category> list` and the `string categoryName` in the signature, but was confused about what `this` does.

So, being a 95% VB guy, I popped the code into my favorite converter and got:

```vb
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Shared Function WithCategoryName(list As IList(Of Category), categoryName As String) As Category

    Return 
    (
        From s In list 
        Where s.Name.Equals(categoryName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        Select s
    )
    .SingleOrDefault()

End Function
```

First of all, I'm not totally sure why `<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>` was included, maybe it's just the converter, nevertheless, as you can see, `this` wasn't converted into anything that I can tell unless it has to do with the aforementioned `<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>`.

So the questions are:

1. **What does `this` actually refer to and/or do in the C# method signature?**
2. **Is there a VB.NET equivalent?**

---

### Response to Question 1:

So we've definitely clarified that `this` ***does in fact*** denote an extension method and that from the answers given, it seems there's no inline VB equivalent.

I would like to add that since I mentioned the [ASP.NET MVC Storefront](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-1/aspnet-mvc-storefront/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-8-testing-controllers-iteration-1-complete) video, the C# example above was pulled from his `CategoryFilters` class.  I assume this is how you implement what was referenced as a *pipes and filters* or *pipeline* methodology.

---

### Response to Question 2:

I assume VB.NET's way of handling extension methods is something like this for example:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices 

Public Module StringExtensions 

    <Extension()> _ 
    Public Function IsNullOrBlank(ByVal s As String) As Boolean 
       Return s Is Nothing OrElse s.Trim.Length.Equals(0) 
    End Function 

End Module
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972433/what-does-this-mean-when-used-as-a-prefix-for-method-parameters

Comment: In regards to your edit, VB.NET assumes the first parameter's type is the type you are extending.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is an extension method. The `this` specifies that it is an extension method of `this <parameter>` type, in your case, `IList<Category>`.

[There is a VB.NET equivalent here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx), though it is an attribute, not a keyword.

Extension methods need to know the type to apply to, note that this is apparent with generics. An extension method:

```
public static string GetNameOf(this List<Category> category) { return ""; }
```

Will not be available on anything other than `List<Category>`.

Answer (score 7):

this appearing in that place means an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int WordCount(this String str)
        {
            return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, 
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
        }
    }   
}
```

after this code *any* string object in your program can use this function, like

```
int count = "Hello world".WordCount();  //count would be equal 2
```

**In other words this is a way to extend the functionality of the types of which you do not have access or  not allowed to change or derive from.**

Answer (score 6):

This creates an extension method.

VB.Net doesn't have a corresponding syntax for this, so you need to apply the attribute yourself.

Comment: Oh ok, ok. I'm on the same page. VB's equivalent is not really an inline equivalent, but in the sense, you can create a Module class that groups a set of extensions that latch onto whatever class you want. For example: 

`Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module StringExtensions

<Extension()> _
Public Function IsNullOrBlank(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
    Return s Is Nothing OrElse s.Trim.Length.Equals(0)
End Function

End Module`

Comment: Exactly.  (Note that .Net already has `String.IsNullOrWhitespace`)

Comment: Right, I know that, but in my simple extensions module I have I don't want to pass parameters, I wanted it to chain off of any existing string.

Comment: Thanks for the first and correct response, but for future visitors' sake, I'm going to mark @AdamHouldsworth's answer as the answer due to his explanation and linking to the VB equivalent.